# How can i call a controller method from jquery in my cshtml file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to call a function in my controller class that adds user information to the database. The users information is given in a form i created in a .cshtml file that interacts with an external javascript file. 
Is there anyway i can call my controller method from my javascript file?

```
public static void createUser(String email, String pw, String fn, String ln)           
    {    
        try
        {               
            connect();   
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_addContact", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@email", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = email;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@password", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = pw;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@firstName", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value =fn;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@lastName", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = ln;                
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            disconnect();
        }
    }// end of loginController.cs
```

[my Project structure looks like this](https://twitter.com/DevJev/status/474576142553198592/photo/1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can submit your form via jQuery ajax

```
$('#YourForm').submit(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 var FormData=$('#YourForm').serialize();
 $.post("/controller/action", {data:FormData}, function(result){
  //success callback
 });    
});
```